# Can I derive the first moment when I am know the second and forth?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

So I know what $E[X^2]$ and $E[X^4]$ are and I need the first moment. Would it be a right approach for me to use the equality below

$$E[X^4] - E[X^2] = (E[X^2] - E[X^1])\times(E[X^2] + E[X^1])$$

If not is there another way to find the first moment using these two? I have the function but integrating is kinda tough so I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that identity is true?

Comment: @coffeemath from the identity $a^2 - b^2 = (a - b)(a + b)$, I am not sure if it would work here though.

Comment: The reason I wanted to try that was because the question gave those information and I don't really have anywhere to use them.

Comment: It would greatly improve your post if you include the actual question which gave information about some of the moments and asked you to find another moment. Include anything which goes with the question, such as any other assumptions about the probability distributions involved.

Comment: By the way, your conjectured equation about the moments more closely looks like the false algebra statement $a^4-b^2=(a^2-a)(a^2-a).$ So I think you ment one of the minus signs on the right to be a plus. But as I say those kinds of relations do not typically give true statements about moments. For example $E(x^2) \neq E(x) \cdot E(x).$

Comment: @coffeemath yes that was my intention, I fixed it. The function is $f(x; \theta) = x\theta^{-x^2/2}log\theta$ and I need to show that the MLE is consistent for which I have been trying to find the expected value but I have been struggling with the integration. I am a real mess in Statistics, I don't really know how else would I be able to find it.

Comment: You need to say what the domain is on the function $f(x;\theta).$ For example is it $[0,\infty)$ or maybe $[0,1]$ or what? And is $\theta$ an unspecified constant while $x$ is the variable? Also what does "MLE" stand for?

Comment: @coffeemath this is the full question: Let $\theta > 1$ be an unknown parameter and $X_{1}, X_{2},...X_{n}$ a random sample with the probability density function given by $f(x; \theta) = x\theta^{-x^2/2}log\theta{\bf1}_{(0, \infty)}(x)$. We assume it is known that the second moment is equal to $2/{log\theta}$ and the forth moment is equal to $8/{(log\theta)}^2$. Find the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}_{n}$ for $\theta$ and show that it is a consistent estimator.

Comment: Ah, alright, I solved it. Apparently when I try to take $E[\hat{\theta}_n]$ I get the result in terms of the second moment which then equates to $\theta$ so I don't really need the first moment. I still don't know why the forth moment was given though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137093/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-mold).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to know $E[X]$ only from $E[X^2]$ and $E[X^4]$. For instance, if you have $Y=-X$, then $E[Y^2]=E[X^2]$ and $E[Y^4]=E[X^4]$, but $E[Y]=-E[X]$.

Comment: Moreover, if $X$ takes the value $1$ with probability $p$ and $-1$ with probability $1-p$, then $E[X^2]=E[X^4]=1$ while $E[x]=2p-1$, which can take any value between $-1$ and $1$.